# Cannot change size of Borderlayout

Tags: java, resize

Good day,

I'm building a java prorgam but I'm unable to change the size of the borderlayouts, using setSize or SetMaximumSize or setPreferredSize. It cause me visual problems
for example I have a very big combobox on the  bottom  of my soft (see attached image). The container of my combobox combobox2 "pane2.setSize(new Dimension(50,50))" can't be resized.

See snapshot: [Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPdkc.jpg)

[image]

Thanks for your help.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class TabbedPane extends JFrame {

    public TabbedPane() {

         //This will create the title you see in the upper left of the window    
        setTitle("Sabre Local Data writer 1.0");  
        setSize(600,800); //set size so the user can "see" it
        setResizable(false);


        JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();

        //This creates the template on the windowed application that we will be using
       getContentPane().add(jtp);

       JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();//This will create the first tab
       JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();//This will create the second tab
       JPanel jp3 = new JPanel();

       jp1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(75, 75, 75, 75));

       //Type JTextField

       JTextField names = new JTextField(50);       
       JTextField pass = new JTextField(10);


       //Type  JComboBox
       JComboBox combo1 = new JComboBox();
       combo1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
       combo1.addItem("Option 1");
       combo1.addItem("Option 2");
       combo1.addItem("Option 3");
       combo1.addItem("Option 4");

       //Type  JComboBox
       JComboBox combo2 = new JComboBox();
       combo2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
       combo2.addItem("Option 1");
       combo2.addItem("Option 2");
       combo2.addItem("Option 3");
       combo2.addItem("Option 4");

       //Type  JTextArea
       JTextArea textarea1 = new JTextArea("", 20, 20);  

       //Type  JRadioButton
       JRadioButton radio1 = new JRadioButton("Item 1");
       JRadioButton radio2 = new JRadioButton("Item 2");


       ButtonGroup radiogroup1 = new ButtonGroup();
       radiogroup1.add(radio1);
       radiogroup1.add(radio2);

       //Type  JCheckBox    
      JCheckBox check1 = new JCheckBox("Case 1");
      JCheckBox check2 = new JCheckBox("Case 2");

      ButtonGroup checkboxgroup1 = new ButtonGroup();
      checkboxgroup1.add(check1);
      checkboxgroup1.add(check2);


    //Type  FileChooser   
      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      chooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());


       jp1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

       JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
       pane.add(new JLabel("Username: "));
       pane.add(names);
       pane.add(new JLabel("Password: "));
       pane.add(pass);
       pane.add(new JLabel("Veuillez Sélectionner un fichier: "));
       JButton select = new JButton("Parcourir");
       pane.add(select);
       pane.add(new JLabel("Veuillez Sélectionner une option: "));
       pane.add(combo1);
       pane.add(new JLabel("Veuillez saisir un texte: "));
       pane.add(textarea1);
       pane.add(new JLabel("Veuillez sélectionner une option: "));
       pane.add(radio1);
       pane.add(radio2);
       pane.add(new JLabel("Veuillez cocher une option: "));
       pane.add(check1);
       pane.add(check2);
       pane.add(new JLabel(""));
       JButton submit = new JButton("Valider");
       pane.add(submit);
       //submit.addActionListener(new Handler());
       jp1.add(pane);


       //This adds the first and second tab to our tabbed pane object and names it
       jtp.addTab("Insérer données", new ImageIcon("saisie.png"), jp1);
       jtp.addTab("Liste Saisies", new ImageIcon("liste.png"), jp2);
       jtp.addTab("Configuration", new ImageIcon("configuration.png"), jp3);

        //This creates a new button called "Press" and adds it to the second tab
       JButton test = new JButton("Press");
       jp2.add(test);



       jp2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


       // Create columns Settings
       String columnNames1[] = { "Position", "Heure et date", "Consulter", "Action" };

       // Create some data
       String dataValues1[][] =
       {
           { "12", "234", "Consulter", "Effacer" },
           { "-123", "43", "Consulter", "Effacer" },
           { "93", "89.2", "Consulter", "Effacer" },
           { "279", "9033", "Consulter", "Effacer" }
       };

       // Create a new table instance
       JTable table1 = new JTable(dataValues1, columnNames1);

       // Add the table to a scrolling pane
       JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
       jp2.add( scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

       jp3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


       // Create columns Settings
       String columnNames[] = { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" };

       // Create some data
       String dataValues[][] =
       {
           { "12", "234", "67" },
           { "-123", "43", "853" },
           { "93", "89.2", "109" },
           { "279", "9033", "3092" }
       };

       // Create a new table instance
       JTable table = new JTable(dataValues, columnNames);

       // Add the table to a scrolling pane
       JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
       jp3.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

       JPanel pane2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
       pane2.setSize(new Dimension(50,50));
       pane2.add(combo2);
       jp3.add( pane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //This is an Action Listener which reacts to clicking on 
        //the test button called "Press"
        ButtonHandler phandler = new ButtonHandler();
        test.addActionListener(phandler);
        setVisible(true); //otherwise you won't "see" it 
    }

    //This is the internal class that defines what the above Action Listener
    //will do when the test button is pressed.
    class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I've been pressed", "What happened?", JOptionPane. INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
           }
    }

    //example usage
     public static void main (String []args){
        TabbedPane tab = new TabbedPane();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd put the _bottom_ component in the _bottom_ (aka south) position and not in the center position. Center should contain the table.

Answer (score 0):

So what do you want to resize?
An element or just the whole layout.

My first guess would be that you should call this.pack() after creating the JPanel, but if that doesn't solve your problem please elaborate on your problem.